# Modificar sesión de un usuario, cuando otro realiza una acción

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, real-time

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando un usuario envíe un mensaje a otro usuario, al receptor le aparezca un "(+1)" en la pestaña de "Mensajes".

El problema es que esa pestaña se encuentra en el header.jsp, vista que no recibe atributos de ningún controlador, por lo que no podría simplemente pasarle un registro de la base de datos con dicho número.

Lo que se me ocurre es que ese número debe modificarse como un atributo de sesión de ese usuario y llamarlo en la vista, pero no encuentro la manera de modificar la sesión del usuario receptor cuando el emisor envía el mensaje, ya que quiero que ese número se actualice incluso si el receptor ya está logueado.

Esta es la parte del header donde querría añadir ese número de mensajes nuevos:

```
<security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
   <a id="mensajes" class="nav-item nav-link" href="carpeta/list.do"> 
       <spring:message code="master.page.mensajes"/>
   </a>
</security:authorize>
```

Comment: Podrias copiar el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: No he intentado nada en código ya que no sé cómo acceder a la sesión de otro usuario para modificarle un atributo cuando se está ejecutando código del principal. He estado buscando pero no he sacado nada en claro

Comment: Si querés que eso pase "en el momento", necesitas usar websockets para que el servidor pueda enviar mensajes asíncronos a los clientes que estén conectados. De otro modo, solo podes actualizar el número de mensajes en la base de datos y envíar el nuevo número cuando el cliente receptor ejecute alguna interacción con el sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Veo dos formas de hacerlo:

- Acoplada:  Meter los datos los datos de usuario en sesión y realizar una llamada Ajax que recargue el header de la página y con ello ese dato.
- Desacoplada: Hacer un componente de React/Vue/Angular/jQuery que se encargue de esa funcionalidad.

En mi opinión no merece la pena montar una estructura de websockets.